# ASP.NET MVC Metro Style

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Anybody tried ASP.NET MVC Metro style look with jQuery UI. I'm looking for ready available skins/themes or plugins.

anybody has idea where to look..

thx

Answer (score 11):

There are many.

If you have SVN, then download a sample from
https://github.com/rwhitmire/MetroMvc

Tutorials from

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/f90d5571-ff80-4f87-ac77-c217a5a22139

http://code52.org/metro.css/

http://stephenwalther.com/

Themes from

http://code.google.com/p/jq-metro/

http://www.jqmetro.com/Pages/

http://jquit.com/builder/

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/metro

http://www.dustinhorne.com/post/2012/02/21/Metro-Style-UI-With-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check this link...

Metro themes and websites

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/everything-you-need-to-create-windows-8-metro-ui-styled-websites/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138661/Metro-UI-Zune-like-Interface-form

Answer (score 1):

One more! Coooool

http://metroui.org.ua/

this support menu component: menu navigation, table and more...